# change grocery crud texteditor options to simple from advanced

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, tinymce, grocery-crud

As the title reads, I have been trying to figure out how to be able to use tinymce's "simple" theme instead of the default "advanced". The advanced theme is way more options/buttons then I need. I have tried:

editting : jquery.tine_mce.config.js under

assets\grocery_crud\js\jquery_plugins\config

```
theme : "simple"
```

This does not work however. Any suggestions?

Is there a way to change the setting thru grocery crud? ie..

```
$this->crud->set_texteditor_simple();
```

Comment: +1 good question, looks like you are on the right way. but this does not seem to be the right place of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me with the grocery crud 1.2.3 
This is what I changed

```
/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/config/jquery.tine_mce.config.js line 8
```